# How to pass values from a post and extract with GET

Tags: php

I have three pages One with HTML with the form (input variable) and its going to  POST the variable to linkslvl2.php . With my third page i want to use the GET function and retrieve the variables from linkslvl2.php. When i click on the process i want it to automatically process linkslvl2 and print linkslvl3 statement.  I'm stumped on how to pass it the variables along.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Super Hero</h1>

<form action="linklvltwo.php" method="post">
```

Please Enter a name:

Enter A super Hero Name:

Enter your weakness:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$name = $_POST['namep'];
$superHero = $_POST['superhero'];
$weakness = $_POST['weakness'];
?>
</body>
</html>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php

$person = $_GET['name'];
$chosenhero = $_GET['superHero'];
$chosenweakness = $_GET['weakness'];


print"
 <p>$person you have chosen $chosenhero as you super hero, and your weakness $chosenweakness</p>
  "


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do that? If you want `GET` - submit with `GET`.

Comment: Why do you want to use this

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try using $_REQUEST which gives you the parameters wether they are posted or "getted".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this type of works in two way: 1) you can use db, file, session to save the value after submitting each form and use an id to indentify/get the previous values. 2) you can Submit the values of each steps via